# How to fetch a custom SELECT query in Flask?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, peewee, flask-peewee

I'd like to fetch this custom query on [Flask-Peewee](http://flask-peewee.readthedocs.org/)

```
SELECT A.* , haversine('34.0160',' -118.4925', A.lat, A.long, 'MILES') AS dist FROM merchant_details A HAVING haversine('34.0160', '-118.4925', A.lat, A.long, 'MILES') <6000
```

I tried the following piece of code code but didn't work and I'm getting 'long' object has no attribute 'fetchall':

```
@app.route('/api/results/')
def results():
    db = connect_db()
    cur = db.execute("SELECT A.* , haversine('34.0160',' -118.4925', A.lat, A.long, 'MILES') AS dist FROM merchant_details A HAVING haversine('34.0160', '-118.4925', A.lat, A.long, 'MILES') <6000 LIMIT 1")
    entries = [dict(id=row[0], merchant_id=row[1], merchant_name=row[2], first_name=row[3]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    return repr(entries)
```

Any help would be greatfully appreciated.

EDITED>

Here is connect_db function:

```
from torndb import Connection

LOCALHOST = "localhost"
DBNAME = "XXXX"
DBUSER = "XXXX"
DBPASSWORD = "XXXX"


    #connect with DB
    def connect_db():
        db = Connection(LOCALHOST,DBNAME, user=DBUSER, password=DBPASSWORD)
        return  db

    #close the connection from DB
    def close_db(db):
        db.close()
```

Comment: What is `connect_db`? I don't see that function in neither the Peewee nor the Flask-Peewee API, so this must be a function you defined. We don't know what `db` is so we can't definitively tell you why you are getting that error.

Comment: @MarkHildreth Sorry I just edited the question and connect_db() is my 2nd connection to connect to mysql, but I don't think you need more information to answer my question, Do you know any other way to run custom query in flask-peewee like above query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With flask-peewee if you want to run a SQL query you can do:

```
db = Database(app)
db.database.execute_sql("some query", [param1, param2])
```

If `MerchantDetails` is a model, you could try:

```
dist = fn.haversine(
    34.0160, 
    -118.4925, 
    MerchantDetails.lat, 
    MerchantDetails.long, 
    'MILES')
MerchantDetails.select(MerchantDetails, dist.alias('dist')).having(dist < 6000)
```

To get:

```
SELECT A.* , haversine('34.0160',' -118.4925', A.lat, A.long, 'MILES') AS dist 
FROM merchant_details A 
HAVING haversine('34.0160', '-118.4925', A.lat, A.long, 'MILES') <6000
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that `connect_db()` actually returns a *cursor* and not a db connection.  As such, the return value from `db.execute` would in fact be a *long* (the number of rows returned from the query).  What you should try as a first step would be to change to the following:

```
curr = connect_db()
curr.execute("QUERY")
entries = [... for row in curr.fetchall()]
```

It is also very possible (I did not look at source) that the `connect_db` is returning a new object which wraps the functionality of the connection object and cursor object such that you can interact with it as either.  I have done this in the past myself.  The only oddity is handling of the `close` method, since both cursor and connection define `close`.  In my case, `close` closed both.

**EDIT** based on your comment
Again, without reading the source code for `connect_db()` I can only really guess.  But you may want to try:

```
conn = connect_db()
curr = conn.cursor()
```

And proceed as before.  If that still gives you an error, take a look at its properties and methods by adding a `print dir(conn) after the call to`connect_db()`.  My guess now is that it will show a`cursor` function in that list.

Comment: Thanks for your note, I'm getting "AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'fetchall', is it related to the same issue? or the query runs correctly and this is another issue?